# Is there a flag to allow creating a transaction with multiple outputs to the same address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, createrawtransaction

Does bitcoin core have a flag to allow creating a transaction with multiple outputs to the same address?

Comment: There’s literally no reason to ever do that.

Comment: Could you provide a scenario why you would want to do that? You could of course just send to multiple addresses of the same wallet instead.

Comment: the raw transaction RPC commands will probably allow you to do this

Comment: the reason for doing it is that we run a large retail exchange, and batch tens/hundreds of withdrawals at once. if a some of our customers decide to send to the same address at the same time, we want to have the outputs separate because otherwise the internal tracking would be a lot more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and it is unlikely one will ever be added. There is no reason to make multiple outputs to the same address as it is inefficient and wastes money.